# await for any future asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, executor

I'm trying to use asyncio to handle concurrent network I/O. A very large number of functions are to be scheduled at a single point which vary greatly in time it takes for each to complete. Received data is then processed in a separate process for each output.

The order in which the data is processed is not relevant, so given the potentially very long waiting period for output I'd like to `await` for whatever future finishes first instead of a predefined order.

```
def fetch(x):
    sleep()

async def main():
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch, x) for x in range(50)]
    for f in futures:
       await f

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Normally, awaiting in order in which futures were queued is fine:

[image: Well behaved functions profiler graph]

Blue color represents time each task is in executor's queue, i.e. `run_in_executor` has been called, but the function was not yet executed, as the executor runs only 5 tasks simultaneously; green is time spent on executing the function itself; and the red is the time spent waiting for all previous futures to `await`.

[image: Volatile functions profiler graph]

In my case where functions vary in time greatly, there is a lot of time lost on waiting for previous futures in queue to await, while I could be locally processing GET output. This makes my system idle for a while only to get overwhelmed when several outputs complete simultaneously, then jumping back to idle waiting for more requests to finish.

Is there a way to `await` whatever future is first completed in the executor?

Comment: What did you use to visualize the coroutines execution? :)

Comment: @PovilasB Lots of logging `time.time()` and PIL

Comment: If you're using futures, I found [as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) pretty helpful to process events as they finish.

Comment: ^ as_completed +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) with `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED`.

```
def fetch(x):
    sleep()

async def main():
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch, x) for x in range(50)]
    while futures:
        done, futures = await asyncio.wait(futures, 
            loop=loop, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)  
        for f in done:
            await f

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: There is no need to await each done task. They are done ;-) . One can, however, loop through then to use their value, if needed.

Comment: The most important part is getting an exception if a task has failed. It is a good practice even if the result value is not interesting.