# How to handle tasks with varying completion times

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm watching a video<sup>(a)</sup> on YouTube about `asyncio` and, at one point, code like the following is presented for efficiently handling multiple HTTP requests:

```py
# Need an event loop for doing this.

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Task creation section.

tasks = []
for n in range(1, 50):
    tasks.append(loop.create_task(get_html(f"https://example.com/things?id={n}")))

# Task processing section.

for task in tasks:
    html = await task
    thing = get_thing_from_html(html)
    print(f"Thing found: {thing}", flush=True)
```

I realise that this is efficient in the sense that everything runs concurrently but what concerns me is a case like:

- the first task taking a full minute; but
- all the others finishing in under three seconds.

Because the task processing section awaits completion of the tasks in the order in which they entered the list, it appears to me that ***none*** will be reported as complete until the first one completes.

At that point, the others that finished long ago will also be reported. Is my understanding correct?

If so, what is the normal way to handle that scenario, so that you're getting completion notification for each task the instant that task finishes?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> From Michael Kennedy of "Talk Python To Me" podcast fame. The video is [Demystifying Python's Async and Await Keywords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F19R_M4Nay4) if you're interested. I have no affiliation with the site other than enjoying the podcast, so heartily recommend it.

Comment: True.  But as long as the time-consuming part is in the task, it isn't that costly.  If one task takes 60 seconds, then running the whole task list is going to take a bit over 60 seconds no matter what order you run them.

Comment: @Tim, I have no issue with that aspect but, if you were measuring performance or batching 1000 tasks so that only 100 are running at any given time, wouldn't you want to know when a task completes immediately (to measure it, or kick off the next one). And what of the case where the tasks aren't homogeneous but you don't know that, such as some being quick web requests and some being long running calculations? Wouldn't that be a similar issue?

Comment: Then you wouldn't use that method.  The `as_completed` method returns each awaitable as it completes.

Comment: I think [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407084/335858) is related to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to do something after each task, you can create another async function that does it, and run *those* in parallel:

```
async def wrapped_get_html(url):
    html = await get_html(url)
    thing = get_thing_from_html(html)
    print(f"Thing found: {thing}")

async def main():
    # shorthand for creating tasks and awaiting them all
    await asyncio.gather(*
        [wrapped_get_html(f"https://example.com/things?id={n}")
         for n in range(50)])
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

If for some reason you need your main loop to be notified, you can do that with `as_completed`:

```
async def main():
    for next_done in asyncio.as_completed([
            get_html(f"https://example.com/things?id={n}")
            for n in range(50)]):
        html = await next_done
        thing = get_thing_from_html(html)
        print(f"Thing found: {thing}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the tasks to run in parallel with the code example below. I introduced `asyncio.gather` to make task run concurrently. Also I demonstrated `poison pill` technique and `daemon task` technique.

Please follow comments in code and feel free to ask questions if you have any.

```py
import asyncio
from random import randint

WORKERS_NUMBER = 5
URL_NUM = 20


async def producer(task_q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    """Produce tasks and send them to workers"""
    print("Producer-Task Started")

    # imagine that it is a list of urls
    for i in range(URL_NUM):
        await task_q.put(i)

    # send poison pill to workers
    for i in range(WORKERS_NUMBER):
        await task_q.put(None)

    print("Producer-Task Finished")


async def results_shower(result_q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    """Receives results from worker tasks and show the result"""
    while True:
        res = await result_q.get()
        print(res)
        result_q.task_done()  # confirm that task is done


async def worker(
        name: str,
        task_q: asyncio.Queue,
        result_q: asyncio.Queue,
) -> None:
    """Get's tasks from task_q, do some job and send results to result_q"""
    print(f"Worker {name} Started")
    while True:
        task = await task_q.get()
        # if worker received poison pill - break
        if task is None:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(randint(1, 10))
        result = task ** 2
        await result_q.put(result)
    print(f"Worker {name} Finished")


async def amain():
    """Wrapper around all async ops in the app"""
    _task_q = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=5)  # just some random maxsize
    _results_q = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=5)  # just some random maxsize
    # we run results_shower as a "daemon task", so we never await
    # if asyncio loop has nothing else to do, loop stops  
    # without waiting for "daemon task"
    asyncio.create_task(results_shower(_results_q))
    # gather block means that we run task in parallel and wait till all the task are finished
    await asyncio.gather(
        producer(_task_q),
        *[worker(f"W-{i}", _task_q, _results_q) for i in range(WORKERS_NUMBER)]
    )
    # q.join() prevents loop from stopping, until results_shower print all task result
    # it has some internal counter, which is decreased by task_done and increases
    # q.put(). If counter is 0, the q can join.
    await _results_q.join()
    print("All work is finished!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```