# Why can all() not accept an async generator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Fairly new to async things in Python and trying to understand it more deeply and ran into this seeming inconsistency I'm trying to understand.

Given this setup:

```
async def return_true():  # In my actual use case this executes a DB query that returns True/False
    return True

async def async_range(count):  # In my actual use case this is an iterator as the result of a DB query that may stream results
    for i in range(count):
        yield(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0)
```

When I run this:

```
any(await return_true() async for i in async_range(10))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

When I change it to `any([await return_true() async for i in async_range(10)])` it runs without issue but in my non-toy example means I have to wait for all the DB queries to return when I might not actually care about all of them since the first one to return True means the `any()` will return True.

**So, my question is, is this expected?** Is this just something that Python hasn't gotten around to implementing in an async compatible method yet (are there plans to do that?) or is there a separate library I should be using that implements these built-ins in async compatible ways?

P.S. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407084/1608327) that seems to implement the behavior I'm looking for, but does so in a much more verbose way.

Comment: You'll need to `await` all of them anyway to avoid the `coroutine was never awaited` issue. If `any` short circuits with a result before awaiting each coroutine you wouldn't know which ones hadn't yet been checked.

Comment: I am assuming your question title is wrong because it talks about `all`, while the question itself is about `any`. This is quite the relevant distinction, especially in this asynchronous context. If this is the case, I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76558490/edit) your post title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Different protocols

> Why can `any()` not accept an async generator?

The superficial answer is frustratingly simple: Because it is the wrong type.

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) accepts an [**iterable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), which means an object implementing the `__iter__` method. That is literally the *only* requirement for that protocol. In layman's terms, you must pass something to `any` that would also "work in a `for`-loop".

But the expression

```py
(element async for element in async_iterable)
```

returns an [**asynchronous generator**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-generator-iterator), which is a subtype of the [asynchronous itera**tor**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterator), which in turn is a subtype of the [asynchronous itera**ble**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterable). It is *not* a subtype of the "normal" iterable. It does *not* have the `__iter__` method. It does *not* work in a `for`-loop.

Try to jam an `async_generator` object into a `for`-loop and you'll get that exact `TypeError` you already saw:

```
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

You are dealing with a different protocol that requires a different setup. If you want a function that supports asynchronous iterables, it would **necessarily** have to return a coroutine itself (i.e. you would have to `await` it). [PEP 492](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/#id12) tells us:

> It is a `SyntaxError` to use `async for` outside of an `async def` function.

---

### Side note

I think it is worth mentioning here that asynchronous generators are **never concurrent in their own iteration**; that would not make much sense. They can be concurrent with *other* coroutines in the application. That is their purpose.

This means that the items yielded by something like your `async_range` are still **always yielded sequentially**. It is just that you can run that iteration concurrently with other coroutines and the event loop may switch contexts to those other coroutines in between each iteration.

It helps to remember what `async for` actually represents.

This

```py
async for element in async_iterable:
    ... # do something with `element`
```

is semantically equivalent to this:

```py
async_iterator = async_iterable.__aiter__()
running = True
while running:
    try:
        element = await async_iterator.__anext__()
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        running = False
    else:
        ... # do something with `element`
```

This means you **always** `await` one item after the other, deterministically, sequentially.

I thought it important to mention this because from the way you phrased your question it seemed as though you thought you could somehow run all the coroutines corresponding to your generator items *concurrently*. You **can not** because in your example they are not independent of one another. The next element from the async iterator is only yielded after the previous has been **awaited**.

---

### DIY `any` solution

It is fairly straightforward to implement an asynchronous counterpart to `any`  yourself.

Remember that the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function is semantically equivalent to this:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable


def any(iterable: Iterable[object]) -> bool:
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

In words: "Keep grabbing one element after another from the iterable, until one of them is truthy."

The `async` version would look like this:

```py
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable


async def async_any(async_iterable: AsyncIterable[object]) -> bool:
    async for element in async_iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

So if you want, you can replace the built-in `any` with your own overloaded function that works on both asynchronous and non-asynchronous iterables like this:

```py
import builtins
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable, Awaitable, Iterable
from typing import Union, overload


async def async_any(async_iterable: AsyncIterable[object]) -> bool:
    async for element in async_iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False


@overload
def any(iterable: AsyncIterable[object]) -> Awaitable[bool]: ...


@overload
def any(iterable: Iterable[object]) -> bool: ...


def any(
    iterable: Union[AsyncIterable[object], Iterable[object]]
) -> Union[Awaitable[bool], bool]:
    if isinstance(iterable, AsyncIterable):
        return async_any(iterable)
    return builtins.any(iterable)
```

This will obviously still necessitate `await`ing the coroutine returned in case you pass an asynchronous iterable to it. But you could now at least *call* it either way.

Demo: (with the custom `any`)

```py
from asyncio import run, sleep
from collections.abc import AsyncIterator


async def async_range(count: int) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
    for i in range(count):
        print("yielding", i)
        yield i
        await sleep(0.1)


async def main() -> None:
    if await any(i >= 2 async for i in async_range(5)):
        print("At least one greater or equal to 2")
    else:
        print("All less than 2")

    if any(i >= 5 for i in range(5)):
        print("At least one greater or equal to 5")
    else:
        print("All less than 5")


run(main())
```

Output:

```
yielding 0
yielding 1
yielding 2
At least one greater or equal to 2
All less than 5
```

I am not sure, if this is a good idea, but as you can see it is possible. The danger I see here is that you could *forget* to `await` the asynchronous version and the coroutine object returned is always truthy. But you would at least get a warning from the interpreter about never having awaited it.

As to why this not supported out of the box and whether there even are plans for it, I don't know.

I found a library called [`asyncstdlib`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) that aims to fill this gap. Its [async-`any`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/asyncstdlib/builtins.html#any) implementation is different in principle from what I showed above in that it *always* returns a coroutine because it wraps regular iterables in asynchronous ones internally.

---

If you are interested in more details about all the protocols involved here, you may want to check out this question:

[In Python, what is the difference between `async for x in async_iterator` and `for x in await async_iterator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75372032/19770795)